# Visual Basic Fill Array with simple number set

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I need to fill an array with numbers 1-50, and I currently have the code:

```
Dim numberSet(49)
For x = 1 To 50
numberSet(x - 1) = x
Next x
```

The challenge is to do it in the least amount of lines possible. This part is bugging me because it seems like i shouldn't be using 4 lines for something so basic.

Any thoughts from you guys? I want to avoid doing something like `= {1,2,3,4,5...50}` if I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one line:

```
Dim numberSet(49): For x = 1 To 50: numberSet(x - 1) = x: Next x
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do something like `={1-50}` ?

Comment: Not that I know of in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

One line (but it creates a 1-based array...)

```
Sub TT()

    Dim arr

    arr = Application.Transpose([=ROW(A1:A50)])

    Debug.Print UBound(arr)
    Debug.Print arr(1)
    Debug.Print arr(13)

End Sub
```

...and if you turn off `Option Explicit` you can skip the declaration.  But don't do that ;-)